# A cauchy shwatrz problem that involves exponents and variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x, y,$ and $z$ be real numbers such that$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1.$ Find the maximum value of $9x+12y+8z.$

I feel like it's a cauchy shwartz problem, but idk. I was thinking about making $x=y=z$, or at least very close, but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have

$$(9^2+12^2+8^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2) \geq (9x+12y+8z)^2 \Longleftrightarrow 9x+12y+8z \leq 17$$